# Unable to Change the navigation path when navigating from one component page to another component page

Tags: angular

i have 3 components namely landing page,dashboard, my account components.
Dashboard component is the parent for My-Account. I want to navigate from landing page component to dashboard , then the navigation path is not changing, when i inject the my-account component in dashboard template..
If i remove my-account component from dashboard then navigation path is changing.

Below is my code :

Router navigation from landing page to dashboard
**this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);**

Injection of my-account in dashboard

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="row removeMargins"
            style="background-color: rgb(37, 38, 37);">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
                <h4 style="color: white">MY ACCOUNT</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2" align="right">
                <span> <i class="fa fa-times closeButton" aria-hidden="true"
                    style="margin-top: 9px;"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <my-account></my-account>
</div>
```

And My Account Code is:

```
<div><h1>My-Account</h1></div>
```

Comment: you might have some errors in `my-account` component. pls check the console or paste some code.

Comment: Thank you Sravan. i found the problem.

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: i have bind ngmodel  without any referance of an object in my Component class.